# Using regex for type validation

Tags: python, regex, function, boolean

I'm stating to learn regex and I'm trying to solve a problem using it.
I need to write a function that gets a VCF file and need to check some columns in the files and see if they stand the requirements.

The first column should start with “chr” and end with any number between 1-99 or one of the letters “M,X,Y”.
Second column need to be all int numbers that are bigger than 0.
4th and 5th columns need to be one of the next letters “ATCG” (only one of them).
If one of the statements are wrong even in one row it should return false.

there's the code I wrote:

```
def isVCF(file):
    with open(file, "r+") as my_file:
        lines = my_file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            columns = line.split("\t")
        num_format = re.compile("^[+]?[1-9][0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$")
        if (re.match(r"^chr(?:[1-9][0-9]?|[XYM])$", columns[0]) 
            and re.match(num_format, columns[1])
            and re.match(r"^[ATGC]$", columns[3]) 
            and re.match(r"^[ATGC]$", columns[4])): 
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I checked two files - one should return True and the other False, But I get True on both of them, so I tried to do the test line by line and still got True.
example of the file:

```
ChrX, 74226650, ., T, C, 50, ., DP=385;VDB=0;SGB=-0.693147;RPB=0.982669;MQB=1;BQB=0.947576;MQ0F=0;AC=2;AN=2;DP4=0,95,0,289;MQ=20, GT:PL:DP, 1/1:78,127,0:384
```

the output should be or true or false depends on the conditions.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why regular expressions? For first column it could be a good option, but for others it much easier to use [`columns[1].isdecimal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal) and `columns[3] in {'A', 'T', 'G', 'C'}`.

Comment: Im new to it and I know that I can use other easier way to solve it, but I want to practice regex

Comment: Could you provide a sample VCF file and the exact expected output for it? Thanks

Comment: @ggorlen I couldnt find where I upload a file but I added an image of it

Comment: Thanks, but it's impossible to really tell what's going on at a character level from an image, for example, whether it's tabs or spaces (how many spaces?) delimited, hidden characters, unicode characters that look like ASCII characters, etc etc, so it requires making assumptions/guesses that probably result in wrong answers -- not helpful for you or anyone else. I can't tell from this whether there are two newlines between text lines or just one. Can you post [text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) please? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen I edited it again and put the first line from the file, hope its good enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to solve the problems one by one:

- *The first column should start with `chr` and end with any number between `1-99` or one of the letters `M,X,Y`* - `chr(?:0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[MXY])`
- *Second column need to be all int numbers that are bigger than `0`* - `0*[1-9][0-9]*`
- *4th and 5th columns need to be one of the next letters “ATCG” (only one of them)* - `[ATCG]`.

Now, considering the column delimiter is the one you used in the code sample (a TAB char, `\t`), you can use

```py
def isVCF(file):
    num_format = re.compile(r"^chr(?:0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[MXY])\t0*[1-9][0-9]*\t[^\t]*(?:\t[ATCG]){2}\t", re.I)
    with open(file, "r+") as my_file:
        for line in my_file:
            if not num_format.match(line):
                return False
        return False
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eeGrEM/1/).

Note I used `re.I` to turn on case insensitivity because you use both `chr` and `Chr` in the question, if you need to only match `Chr` and `chr` this way, remove `re.I` and replace `chr` with `(?i:chr)`.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `chr` (start of Column 1) - a `chr` string
- `(?:0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[MXY])` (end of Column 1): an optional `0` and then a non-zero digit, or a digit from `1` to `9` and then any one digit (`0` - `99`), or a letter from `MXY` set
- `\t` - a tab
- `0*[1-9][0-9]*` (Column 2): zero or more `0`s, a non-zero digit and then any zero or more digits
- `\t` - a tab
- `[^\t]*` (Column 3) - any zero or more chars other than a tab
- `(?:\t[ATCG]){2}` (Column 4 and 5) - tab, a letter from `ATCG` set, two times
- `\t` - a tab.

Comment: Thanks! did you meant that the first return is false and the other is true?
BTW, if I need that the 4th and 5th columns will be “ATCG” (Uppercase only) do I write - ['[ATCG]+]]?

Comment: @ranbar I explained the pattern, it does exactly what you wrote.

Comment: It does, Thank you!